# My second spinner adapter not updated after my first spinner position has changed

Tags: android, json, spinner, adapter

I have two spinner, the first spinner is related to the second spinner.

I'm using JSON to fill the adapter for both of them.

When i start the activity, both of adapter is already filled with a correct data(the first and second adapter is related).

But, when i try to change item position of the first spinner, the second spinner's adapter still contain first loaded data.

What i want is, the second spinner's adapter can dynamically contain a data that related from first spinner, when an item position from first spinner has changed.

I don't know what's the problem, i really need some help.

here's my code :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int position, long id){
                try {
                    JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
                    result = json.getJSONArray("all_state");
                    state.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json2 = result.getJSONObject(i);
                            state.add(json2.getString("state"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ViewState.this, R.layout.spinner_state, state);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent){
        }
    });
```

Comment: try to change adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ViewState.this, R.layout.spinner_state, state);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter); to     adpater = null;               adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ViewState.this, R.layout.spinner_state, state);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @JhamanDas, don't post answer in comment section, they are meant to give suggestion or ask clarification from OP.

Comment: @JhamanDas, it's still not the answer, i've try it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved, the problem is because i put the JSONObject and JSONArray into the same variable "result".

So here's the right code :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int position, long id){
            try {
                JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
                result2 = json.getJSONArray("all_state");
                state.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < result2.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json2 = result2.getJSONObject(i);
                        state.add(json2.getString("state"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ViewState.this, R.layout.spinner_state, state);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent){
    }
});
```